# Join on different columns

Tags: join, inner-join, julia

I want to join 2 dataframes and I'm using the intructions in the Julia guide:
http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/joins_and_indexing.html?highlight=join

```
join(a, b, on = :ID, kind = :inner)
```

Now, how I can join on columns with different names:

- **:ID** for a
- **:name_id** for b

I tried the following but it doesn't work"

```
join(a, b, on = [ :ID, :name_id ], kind = :inner)
```

If not implemented, that would be nice feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs on [DataFrames.jl](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/man/joins/) provide this example:

```
innerjoin(a, b, on = [:City => :Location, :Job => :Work])
```

So for your example:

```
j = innerjoin(a, b, on = :ID => :name_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rename!(b, "name_id", "ID")
j = join(a, b, on = :ID, kind = :inner)
rename!(b, "ID", name_id")
```

The rename changes b, so here I changed it back. (In the general case if there are renaming conflicts within a dataframe you can pick a unique name for each pair of joined names, rename in each dataframe, join and rename back.)

This method is obviously not elegant. It's what I've found so far.

Comment: I gather this actually alters the original `b` object? Is there a way to set names on the fly akin to R's `setNames()`, which edits and returns a copy? If not, then I guess this is the way to go.